# CakePHP rebuild page after unsucess validation

Tags: php, cakephp

I came here to ask them how I can rebuild the HTML page with no success after validation in CakePHP Framework. I explain better, when I submit a form and some data is not validated by CakePHP, he returns to form with the appropriate data filled by me on the screen and the necessary validation error messages. Assuming I have that same HTML page a DIV, which is an accordion, when there is a click somewhere on the accordion opens or closes.

How do you get when the CakePHP Framework return the form to accordion is exactly the same way that was at the time of submit?

Comment: Assuming the acordion is some javascript construct, like jquery UI, it doesn't exists inside the form so it can't be sent back after processing. You probably will need some javascript to save this state somewhere or to send it along and read back after.

Comment: Or, you can submit the form with Ajax, and that way you'd have only the form update, and the rest of the page (accordions etc) remain untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:
1. Use Onsubmit form event to set the hidden variable, that will store the current active accordion panel. In your javascript method you can get the active accordion tab using:

```
var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
```

[Here is the link](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#option-active) to guide you how to get active tab.

2. After submitting the form, show all the errors on top of accordion panel.
   [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630373/show-all-model-validation-errors-on-top-of-the-page-in-cakephp), how you can show all the validation errors on top of the page.
3. Add one extra parameter to $validationErrors containing the active tab.
4. On page load you can open the given tab identified by the parameter you added into the `$validationErrors` array.